# Free fermion OPE

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, fermions, grassmann-numbers, wick-theorem

In Di Francesco's *Conformal Field Theory*, the propagator for the free Majorana fermion theory is given by
$$ \langle{\psi(z) \psi(w)}\rangle = \dfrac{1}{2\pi g} \dfrac{1}{z-w}$$
and the energy-momentum tensor is
$$ T(z) = -\pi g :\psi(z) \partial \psi(z):.$$

I want to compute the central charge of the theory by computing the OPE of the energy-momentum tensor with itself. Performing Wick rotations, I reach the following:

$$ T(z) T(w) \sim 2 \dfrac{T(w)}{(z-w)^2} + \dfrac{\partial T(w)}{(z-w)} + \dfrac14 \dfrac{1}{(z-w)^4} + \pi g \dfrac{1}{(z-w)^3} :\psi(w)\psi(w):, $$

which is exactly the OPE I want, up to a $\psi(w) \psi(w)$ term, obtained by expanding $\psi(z)\psi(w)$ around $w$. On what grounds can I cancel this term? Is it because fermions are Grassmann variables and thus $\psi^2=0$? If yes, is this only zero when the two spinors live at the same point? Otherwise, I would have to cancel the whole $\psi(z) \psi(w)$ term and I would not get the correct OPE in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, $:\psi(w)\psi(w):=0$ because $\psi$ is Grassmann-odd.
2. Yes, $:\psi(z)\psi(w):$ is only zero when $z=w$.